# redirect domain.com/contact.html to newdomain.com/contact.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect an html page which is a contact form like this `www.abc.com/contact.html`  to a different domain but without **www** like this   `xyz.com/contact.html`.

I am having 2 domains with same data (Just the domain names are different). The form on xyz.com is working perfectly fine, but the form on abc.com is not working even though the code on both domains is 100% same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the following lines in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www?.abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ http://xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ http://xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ http://xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Make sure the AllowOverride in your server config or maybe in a vhost is set On for rewrites. 
Better do this way to see if everything works "AllowOverride All"

Comment: I have changed AllowOverride All in apache httpd.conf and after the restart of apache webserver (as i am hosting it on my other computer which is my server) i have reloaded the site www.abc.com/contact.html but it is not getting redirected to http://xyz.com/contact.html

Comment: Try my Edited code above and make sure you clear your browser cache and history. Also if possible, can you paste your httpd.conf complete section where you put AllowOverride All?

Comment: Here is httpd.conf section of AllowOverride All;   
DocumentRoot "D:/WWW"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/WWW">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,All
</Directory>

<Directory "d:\WWW">
    Options All
    Order allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "d:\www\webpage">
    Order allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

Comment: I have tried as you said, cleared browser cache and history , but it is not getting redirected!